# does find_under_expand_skip not work on mac sublime?

Tags: sublimetext2

does find_under_expand_skip not work on mac sublime?

Hi I have been trying this on and off for the last week.

I use the "find_under_expand" all the time and when I heard out the ability to skip certain variables it made total sense but I haven't been able to get this to work. any thoughts?

cheers

Will

Answer (score 2):

find_under_expand_skip is bound to the key sequence `command + k, command + d`.  Since it's a sequence you have to press both keybindings in succession.

Comment: yeah I have tried that one, that's what linux users in my team are getting to work but on mac there seems to be something else. thanks though

Comment: Check if there is a command set to `command + k`.  Sequences can't work if a command is bound to the first keybinding.  To check, type `sublime.log_commands(True)` into the console (`command + \``).  Then press `command + k` and see what's in the console.

Comment: I had the same problem, but on windows. Using the debug command @BoundinCode provided, I found that ctrl + k, ctrl + d was in use by a Diffy package. Removed that package, and it started working.